# How to make a message show up when mouse over icon

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am displaying an icon this way:

```
<?php echo anchor('stuff/edit', '<i class="icon-edit icon-white"></i>', array('class'=>'btn btn-info')); ?>
```

And what I want is that when I hover over the icon with the mouse a message that says "Edit" pops up. Just like with the icons on this board, if you hover over the {} icon a message that says "Code Sample..." shows up. I want that using bootstrap.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to do that using a javascript or jquery onmouseover event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By jQuery solution use jQuery UI

HTML in head tag

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

HTML in BODY tag

```
<a href="#" id="show-option" title="edit"><i class="icon-edit icon-white">icon</i></a>
```

JavaScript

```
$(function() {
    $( "#show-option" ).tooltip({
        show: {
        effect: "slideDown",
        delay: 300
        }
    });
});
```

for additional information see http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/

Answer (score 2):

Its simple, If you want it to show the native way, ie with no customizations and styles, use 'title' attribute;

```
<a href="/path" title="Click me"><i class="icon-edit icon-white"></i></a>
```

For more beautiful and larger messages, you could use bootstrap's TOOLTIP

See [Bootstrap Tooltip](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#tooltips) . Its too easy as:

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Click me"><i class="icon-edit icon-white"></i></a>
```

If you have bootstrap.js included, it will show 'first tooltip'

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if there is a css method for this, however you can add tooltip="string" to asp tags, on html tags use title="string".